# Powershell hangs on startup

Tags: powershell

When I run Powershell it hangs after printing this:

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) 2016 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
```

I'm sure it used to work. Any idea how I can diagnose this? I've tried with `-NoProfile` but that didn't make any difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok don't ask me why but restarting my computer fixed it. Yeay Windows.